# Basics Add Two Numbers NASM, Getting inputs

Tags: nasm

started practicing with nasm this morning , so i graduated from helloworld to addition and subtraction and then area of a triangle

Now i want to get input (Like Prompts) from the user and then add or subtract or multiply
Following this code

how do i go about it

```
section .data

    msg:
    db 'Addition is = %d',10,0

section .text
    extern _printf
    global _main


_main:
    push ebp
    mov esp,epb

    mov eax,5
    add eax,2

    push eax
    push msg

    call _printf

    pop ebp
    mov esp,ebp

    ret
```

Comment: Take a look at scanf - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10973783/2026276

Comment: ok let me see and get back to you, in the meantime, thank you